# string convert into array on the behalf of comma in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have string something like this **"12,13"** and I want to convert into array like this **[12,13]** in controller. I used split function it does not work.

```
 $scope.mySplit = function(string, nb) {
          var array = string.split(',');
          return array[nb];
    }

    $scope.isChecked = function(id,matches) {
       var isChecked = false;
       var arr= [];
       arr = $scope.mySplit(matches,0);
       console.log(arr);
};
```

Comment: Show the split function that you used because that is the most practical way to do so

Comment: arr = matches.split(','); like this

Comment: Also provide your original code and the output it produced. Edit your question to include this.

Comment: I have updated my question please consider it

Comment: What is the result of console.log(array) in split method

Comment: I dont understand the question. you seem to have solved your problem in the question itself

Comment: Tested the split function in here `mySplit('12,13',0)` and the result was `12`. What were you expecting from it? **[12,13]**? Then remove the `nb` from `mySplit`.

Comment: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined, this error is shown me @klauskpm

Comment: Inside `isChecked` do `console.log(matches)` and inside `console.log(string)`. Chances are that either `matches` is not been setted, or the code is using `string` as a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that you did not define `arr` to be a variable as such: `var arr = $scope.mySplit(matches,0);`. Or another variable. Unless you declared it globally somewhere else.

Look at this jsfiddle that works: https://jsfiddle.net/wapp4u5g/